# How to import a JS library to Oracle Apex and change it's name or add an alias

Tags: oracle-apex, apexcharts

I have a library that I am importing like: `#WORKSPACE_FILES#js/d3-sankey#MIN#.js`  in the File URLs part on the Page level.
The way I am used to import it in JS is :
 `import * as d3Sankey from "d3-sankey"` , with an alias  so then later I can use d3Sankey like :

```
`  d3Sankey.sankey()
      .nodeId(({index: i}) => N[i])
      .nodeAlign(nodeAlign)
      .nodeWidth(nodeWidth)
      .nodePadding(nodePadding)
      .extent([[marginLeft, marginTop], [width - marginRight, height - marginBottom]])
    ({nodes, links});`
```

How can I add the d3Sankey alias to the  `#WORKSPACE_FILES#js/d3-sankey#MIN#.js`  in Apex so I can use d3Sankey like in the example above?

This might be silly buy I tried to rename the file to have no dash in it, but it did not work.
I found this similar question [How can I include a .js script in Oracle Apex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67178338/how-can-i-include-a-js-script-in-oracle-apex) but did not help.